# Reading inputs using a linked list, how to start

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

Hi i am writing this piece of code which takes 3 field , store it into struct, but i dont know how to create the node and the function print_planet_list() should walk through the linked list and print out the outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* the struct */
typedef struct{
  char name[128];
  double dist;
  char description[1024];
} planet_t;

/* have to write a definition here */
typedef struct planet_node {
  ???;              /* what to write here? */
} planet_node;

/* Print a list of planets pointed to by ptr */
void print_planet_list(planet_node *ptr){
  while(ptr != NULL){
    printf("%15s %10.2f %s\n",
        new[i].name,
        new[i].dist,
        new[i].description);/* not sure if its correct */
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(){
  char buf[64];
  planet_node *head = NULL;
  int quit = 0;

  do {
    printf("Enter planet name (q quits): ");
    scanf("%s",buf);
    if((strcmp(buf,"q")==0)){
      quit = 1;
    }
    else{
      planet_node *new = (planet_t *) malloc(sizeof(planet_t)*? );      
      strcpy(???);          
      printf("Enter distance and description: ");
      scanf(" %lf ", new[i].dist); 
      gets(new[i].description);    
      ptr->head;           /* Link new node to head */
      ???;         /* Set the head to the new node */
    }
  } while(!quit);

  printf("Final list of planets:\n");
  print_planet_list(head);


  while(head != NULL){
    planet_node *remove = head;
    head = (*head).next;
    free(remove);
       }
    }
```

my desired input is :
Enter planet name (q quits): Earth
Enter distance and description: 0.9 Friendly and hospitable 
Enter planet name (q quits): Mars
Enter distance and description:  1.05 Very cosmopolitan

output:

Mars 1.05 Very cosmopolitan 
Earth 0.90 Friendly and hospitable

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct planet_node {
  char name[128];
  double dist;
  char description[1024];
  struct planet_node *next;


} planet_node;
```

I think this is how you should declare your `planet_node` structure where `next` stores the address of the next node.

Comment: Thanks, is the print_planet_list correct? and how do I link new node to head , and set head to new node?

Comment: Check the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733984/linked-list-program-in-c) for link list functions.